# Check if directory is a subdirectory of specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, directory, subdirectory, penetration-testing

I'm currently developing a Web-App with an SSH-Connection.

One Task is that I need to validate if a directory is below the htdocs-dir of the current user.

Until now, what I did is checking the directory-string for having the htdocs-part at the beginning of the string.
Like

> "/var/users/user/htdocs" is in front of
>   "/var/users/user/htdocs/testDir"

Now i was penetration-testing this and inputted

> "/var/users/user/htdocs/testDir/../../../".

Here's the problem. how can i Check if a Directory is a subdirectory of n-th level of the other directory

Comment: What language are you writing the application in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
find /var/users/user/htdocs -path $(readlink -m /var/users/user/htdocs/testDir/../../../)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readlink` to get the actual resulting path:

```
mybox\> readlink -m /var/users/user/htdocs/testDir/../../../    
/var/users
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html):

```
find /var/users -path `realpath /var/users/user/htdocs/testDir/../..`
```

Plus, it will work with relative paths as well:

```
find `realpath dir` -path `realpath dir/htdocs/testDir/..`
```